# linux bash terminal function not closing on command

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

```
#webstorm terminal window
alias webstorm='webstorm . &'
#function for opening and running AdminApp
ws(){ gnome-terminal -e webstorm && nohup && exit;};
aa(){ cd Desktop/code/AdminApp; ws; nodemon --exec npm start;};
```

My ide is webstorm, what I am trying to accomplish is have one command to cd to correct folder open the ide and then run server locally. For some reason I cannot get the terminal of the ide to close, and if I close it manually then it closes the ide. 
I was also unsuccessful in doing everything in one terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `nohup` *and* `gnome-terminal -e` the wrong way.

With `gnome-terminal -e webstorm && nohup && exit` you are executing three commands in the current shell:

1. `gnome-terminal -e webstorm`
2. `nohup`
3. `exit`

`nuhop` will only run when the first command exits successfully, but that will not happen as long as `webstorm` is running.
If `webstorm` exits `nohup` starts, but that doesn't help you now anymore, especially since `nohup` expects a command as an argument and will fail since you didn't provide one.

The alias `webstorm='webstorm . &'` you defined earlier has no effect on `gnome-terminal -e` as `-e` takes a *string* argument and executes that string in another shell. You have to write out the command.

You probably want to use

```
ws() { nohup webstorm . & }
```